# Не выводятся данные в шаблон

Tags: python, django

Делаю панель с выборкой из базы категории товаров. Сами товары выводятся корректно, но категории не отображаются, оставляя пустое место панели там, где она должна быть.

Код:

```
# models.py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# views.py
class ServiceListView(ListView):
    template_name = "services/list.html"

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        return Service.objects.all()

def service_list_view(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    queryset = Service.objects.all()
    context = {
        'categories': categories,
        'object_list': queryset
    }
    return render(request, "services/list.html", context)

# list.html
<div class='col-3'> 
    <div class="list-group">
        {% for category in categories %}
            {{ category.name }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Какая именно вьюха из показанных двух используется-то?

Comment: последняя вьюха

Comment: Запустил весь этот код у себя, создал две категории — обе отлично вывелись: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG0Dv.png Так что показанный код работает, а вы что-то не договариваете

Comment: url на какую вьюху указывает, на ServiceListView или на service_list_view?

Comment: на ServiceListView

Comment: В ServiceListView вы не получаете категории. Внимательно просмотрите собственный код.

Answer (score 1):

Покажите что у вас `urls.py`.
Я думаю у вас не это `service_list_view` представление используется.
Для того что бы у вас всё заработало импортируйте именно это `service_list_view` представление в urls.py, вы же в нём через словарь `сontext` categories в шаблон отдаёте. Для того что бы передать `context` в этом `ServiceListView` представлении переопределите метод `get_context_data`.

Напишите одно представление, и используйте либо функции, либо классы, что то одно.